# Is this a valid justification that the relation $R$ is not transitive?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

The question I was working on was asking to find whether the relation $R$ defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ by $a\,R\,b$ if $|a-b|\leq 2$ is reflexive, symmetric, and/or transitive and provide justification. I got that it is reflexive, symmetric, and not transitive. I'm just wondering if my justification for it not being transitive works? Here is what I said:

Assume $a\,R\,b$ and $b\,R\,c$. Then $|a-b|\leq 2$ and $|b-c|\leq 2$. This means $|a-b|+|b-c|\leq 4$. Say $a-b$ and $b-c$ are positive. Then $|a-b|+|b-c|=a-b+b-c = a-c = |a-c|\leq 4$. However, this doesn't necessarily mean $|a-c|\leq 2$, since it is possible $2<|a-c|\leq 4$. Therefore, $R$ is not transitive.

(I know that instead of this I could've just given a counterexample, such as $0\,R\,2$ and $2\,R\,4$ but $0\,\not R\,4$. Just wondering if this more general justification works too.)

Comment: Well, saying that something "doesn't necessarily mean" something else is just waving your hands.  In the end, you are going to have to exhibit a counterexample.  Your second argument is, therefore, vastly superior.

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider to provide a counter-example as mentioned by @lulu.

Take $a = 1$, $b = 2$ and $c = 4$.

Then we have that $|a - b| = 1 \leq 2$ as well as $|b - c| = 2 \leq 2$, but $|a - c| = 3 > 2$.

Hence the proposed relation is not transitive.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: The OP provides the example $0\sim 2$ and $2\sim 4$ but $0\not \sim 4$ in the post.  I think they are just asking if the abstract argument they provide would serve as an alternative.

Comment: @lulu I see. I did not pay enough attention to the body of the question.

Comment: I think they just want to know if a more abstract approach is possible.  Which, of course, it may be...though I don't think that what is written in the post would suffice.

Comment: Yes @lulu is right! Thank you for the other counterexample -- that helps!

Comment: @blakedylanmusic You are welcome ! I am glad I could help.